# Permission denied Error when trying to start another executable from Rust

Tags: process, rust

I am trying to start a subprocess in Rust. It is another executable.

Minimal Code looks like this:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("\"./target/release/path_to_binary.exe\"")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command!");
}
```

I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute command!: Os { code: 5, kind: Permi
ssionDenied, message: "Zugriff verweigert" }', src\libcore\result.rs:997:5
```

Comment: Why are there escaped quotes inside your call to `new`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Right, solved. I need those to start an executable from cmd and figured I would need them here too. Can't see how the OS Error comes from that

Answer (score 1):

When removing the escaped quotes( which I set as they are needed to start the process in cmd.exe) it works.